# ExtJS Trying to add records from one grid to another grid allowing duplicates

Tags: extjs, duplicates, grid

I have **two grids** with the same columns. I want to **add records from grid 1 to grid 2** and I want to **allow duplicates** in the second grid. I know stores have an `id` property to not allow duplicates. I override this using `idProperty: 'customId'` config in the model. I'm using an autoincremental `customId` field as the new `idProperty`. But this doesn't work: I click twice or more times at the select column but nothing happens (it only works the first one). How can I solve this?

I did a [fiddle with the example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/34j8&view/editor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are adding record to destination Grid's store, instead of adding record, use record.data property to pass pure data object, not a model object.

```
destinationGrid.getStore().add(record.data);
```

[here is fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/34jc&view/editor)